# How to construct an isomorphism from a group into $D_8$?

Tags: group-theory

I have attempted the following question.
[image]

Here is what I have done but I'm not 100% sure.

Denote the groups $A=\{1,h\}$ and $B=\{1,k,k^2,k^3\}$.

And let $D_8=\{r_1,...,r_4,R_1,...,R_4\}$ where $r_i$ are the reflections $90$ degrees clockwise and $R_i$ are the reflections through the $4$ lines of symmetry.

Since $\phi$ is non trivial then $\phi(1)=\rho_1$ and $\phi(h)=\rho_3$ where $\rho_i$ denotes the automorphism sending each element of $B$ to it's $i$th power. So $\rho_1$ is the identity in $\text{Aut}(B)$ and $\rho_3$ cubes the elements.

Here is where my question begins.

Clearly any isomorphism sends the identity of $G$: $(1,1)$ to the identity in $D_8$.

Now the rest of the elements are

$$(1,k)$$

$$(1,k^2)$$

$$(1,k^3)$$

$$(h,1)$$

$$(h,k)$$

$$(h,k^2)$$

$$(h,k^3)$$

it is easy to see that under the non trivial homomorphism $\phi$ that each of the elements whose first entry is $1$ has order $4$ and any element whose first entry is $h$ has order $2$.

So since the isomorphism must preserve the orders we can see that we must map

$$(1,k)$$

$$(1,k^2)$$

$$(1,k^3)$$

into the elements of order $4$ in $D_8$ (the rotations)

and

$$(h,1)$$

$$(h,k)$$

$$(h,k^2)$$

$$(h,k^3)$$

into the order $2$ elements of $D_8$ (the rotations).

Now I ask this:

Does it matter in which way we now choose to map the elements of order $4$ into each other and likewise for the elements of order $2$?

I ask this because I randomly picked a map and tested a few elements and the isomorphism property seemed to hold (i.e it preserved multiplication).

Was this just a fluke (I suspect not.)

And if not why is it the case that any of these choices work equally well to produce an isomorphism?

Is it just a simple case of isomorphisms are not unique and we don't have many options to construct them in this case (not a lot of elements + restrictions with the orders)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Isomorphisms need not be unique. In fact, if you fix one isomorphism $\phi : G \to D_8$, then its composition with an element of $\text{Aut}(D_8)$ is also an isomorphism from $G$ to $D_8$. Furthermore, this defines a bijection from $\text{Aut}(D_8)$ to the set of isomorphisms from $G$ to $D_8$.

The group $\text{Aut}(D_8)$ is certainly nontrivial. To start with, its center is the order 2 cyclic group generated by $k^2$ (using your notation), and so the group of inner automorphisms $\text{Inn}(D_8) \approx \text{Aut}(D_8) / (\text{Center})$ is of order $4$. There's also a non-inner automorphism of order $2$ which swaps the two order 4 elements of $D_8$, so $\text{Aut}(D_8)$ has order at least 8. Look [here](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/labute/courses/370.97/dihedral.pdf) for an exact formula for $\text{Aut}(D_8)$, showing it has order exactly 8.